# Autoform: can I specify the options helper in the schema?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Is there any way to specify the options helper in the schema? I tried:

*Schema*

```json
{
  favoriteColor: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      options: "colorOptions"
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

The following technique works fine to display a select with options in a form:

*Schema*

```json
{
  favoriteColor: {
    type: String
  }
}
```

*Helper*

```js
Template.myFormTemplate.helpers({
  colorOptions: function () {
    return Colors.find().map(function (c) {
      return {label: c.name, value: c._id};
    });
  }
});
```

*Template*

```
{{> afQuickField name="favoriteColor" options=colorOptions}}
```

In my actual schema I have an array of objects, and in each object I need to select an item from different collection. When you use afArrayField you can no longer set the options in the template as I did in the Template above (because it's an array of objects, and one element in the object would refer the helper).

Is my only option to query the database when I define the scheme? That I guess would make it non reactive, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
  favoriteColor: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      options: function () {
    return Colors.find().map(function (c) {
      return {label: c.name, value: c._id};
    });
  }
    }
  }
}
```

Inserting the helper function directly into the schema will work. I'm doing something similar and it is reactive.

Comment: I'm using this functionality as well, but my options are not showing up. Logging the same function in the console after my schema shows the values I expect from the database. Thoughts?

Comment: @RandyHall make sure you are subscribing to the data you are pulling in for the options.